There is a problem with commiting my app to GitHub after updating pods
I ran pod update on my project then tried to commit the app on my Mac using Github app. I got this error.
error: 'Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/Headers/FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h' is beyond a symbolic link
fatal: Unable to process path Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/Headers/FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h

AI recommended I don't check Pods directory to source control.
However, I see this link in my .gitignore which says keep it checked in.
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control
How do I fix this?

Try:
git add  .
Before the commit.
Check out this reference: Git file is beyond a symbolic link

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

When using pods, I've generally found its best practices not to commit the pods to the project, it just makes the project bigger and you can't be certain that your pods will work on someone else's machine.
In your case it might be worth just running a clean install of pods and trying the commit again.
pod cache clean --all
pod deintegrate
pod install

Depending on how many pods you have the re-install might take a while, especially if you're dealing with the Firebase Pod.
